# Is it possible to have four points, in which the length between each of them is an integer?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Is it possible to have four points on a plane, which the length between each of those points (six lengths) can be divided by an integer to get 1? Give an example of this, with the lengths between each point shown.

If you can, what about 5? What about 6?

[image]

Comment: What is a whole number here? Integer?

Comment: yes.............

Comment: Saying "the length can be divided by an integer to get $1$" is just a roundabout way to say "the length is an integer", right? If so, there is a configuration of seven points in the plane, no three in a line, no four on a circle, such that all distances are integers. No such configuration of eight points is known. See, e.g., https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182577/maximum-number-of-general-position-points-with-mutual-rational-distances

Comment: This question needs some kind of [general position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_position) stipulation otherwise we can just put as many points as we like on a single line.

Comment: @nickg what's needed is what's in my comment: no three in a line, no four on a circle.

Comment: Care to engage with my first comment, Josh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any Pythagorean triple $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$ with $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ the four points
\begin{equation}
(0,0), (a,0), (a,b) \text{ and } (0, b)
\end{equation}
satisfy the given constraints.

Comment: Is this the only way, that you know of?